# includeSelectAllOption: true is not working when i used ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

select all option is not working in my second drop down its working for first dropdown where i fetch dropdown options from database while in my second dropdown i hardcoded dropdown option.

```
<?php
include_once("connection.php");
$query="select distinct Type,typeId from mst ORDER BY Type";
$result1=mysqli_query($con,$query);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
Multistep Form With Checkbox
</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<style type="text/css">
#register_form fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
display: none;
}
</style>
<script src="multistepjsfile.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<h2>Example: Multi Step Form using jQuery, Bootstrap and PHP</h2>
<div class="progress">
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
<div class="alert alert-success hide"></div>
<form id="register_form" novalidate action="form_action.php" method="post">
<fieldset>
<h2>Step 1: Select Type </h2>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="Qtype">Types*</label>
<select name="type" id="type" multiple="multiple">
            <?php
                foreach($result1 as $type)
                {
            ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $type['typeId']?>"><?php echo $type['Type']?></option>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
</select>
</div><br/><br/>
<input type="button" id="btnone" class="next-form btn btn-info" value="Next"/>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<h2> Step 2: Select Locations</h2>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="Qlocation">Locations*</label>
<select name="location[]" id="location" multiple="multiple">
</select>
</div><br/><br/>
<input type="button" name="previous" class="previous-form btn btn-default" value="Previous" />
<input type="button" name="next" class="next-form btn btn-info" value="Next" />
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#type').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function () {
        $('#location').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#btnone').click(function () {
        var selected = $("#type option:selected");
        var stateID = "";
        selected.each(function () {
        stateID += $(this).val() + ",";
        });
        stateID=stateID.substring(0, stateID.length - 1);
        //alert(stateID);
         if(stateID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'FetchTypeN.php',
                data:'state_id='+stateID,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#location').html('');
                    $('#location').multiselect('destroy');
                    $('#location').html(html);
                    $('#location').multiselect('refresh');
                    $('#location').multiselect();
                }
            });
        }
     });
});  
</script>
```

FetchTypeN:-

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
if(isset($_POST["state_id"]) && !empty($_POST["state_id"])){
    if($_POST["state_id"]=='2')
    {
    ?>
       <!--<option value="00"><b>Select all</b></option>-->
       <option value="03">BM</option>
    <?php       
    }
    else if($_POST["state_id"]=='1')
    {
    ?>          
                <option value="06">GL</option>
                <option value="07">CP</option>
                <option value="08">RO</option>
                <option value="09">DR</option>
                <option value="10">DP</option>
                <option value="11">MZ</option>
                <option value="12">BP</option>
    <?php               
    }
    else
    {
    ?>
                <option value="03">BM</option> 
                <option value="06">GL</option>
                <option value="07">CP</option>
                <option value="08">RO</option>
                <option value="09">DR</option>
                <option value="10">DP</option>
                <option value="11">MZ</option>
                <option value="12">BP</option>
    <?php           
    }
}
?>
```

In my first dropdown i.e. type its working but in my second dropdown i.e. location selectall option is not there..am i doing something please give correct code for this..Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

step 1: Load the element first with options through jquery or any other source.

step 2: Apply `.multiselect({ includeSelectAllOption: true})` this option true for it.

Note: if You apply `includeSelectAllOption: true` first then it will dropdown or listbox will not work